# React component not rendering result as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, typeerror

I have a ReactComponent that queries a rest API and renders its result as a HTML table. The result is a JSON in the following form:

```
{
  timestamp: ",
  message: "",
  requestId: "",
  responseData: []
}
```

The ResultTable react component is given below and it is expected to render `responseData` which is a list. Here is the problems I see:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

So looks like the data is not being fetched from the REST API in time to render. How can I fix this. Please find the code for the component below. Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export class ResultTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fetchedJson: [],
      fooBar: false
    };
  }

  handleSubmit(selectedRecipes) {
    if (!this.state.fooBar) {
      let url =
        "http://localhost:8080/ingredients/?recipes=" +
        selectedRecipes.join(",");
      console.log(url);
      axios.get(url).then(res => {
        this.setState({
          fetchedJson: res.data,
          fooBar: true
        });
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    this.handleSubmit(this.props.recipeList);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 align="center">Ingredients</h1>
        <table border="1" align="center">
          <tbody>
            {this.state.fetchedJson.responseData.map(function(ingredient, ingredientIndex) {
              return (
                <tr key={ingredientIndex}>
                  <td>{ingredient.name}</td>
                  <td>{ingredient.amount}</td>
                  <td>{ingredient.unit}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try `console.log(res.data)` or console logging state to check what is being updated in state

Comment: @sumanthmadishetty That's totally worth to check first. My assumption is that maybe `res.data` is the array itself where the `map()` needs to be used but that's just a guess. We need to see the result of `res.data`.

Comment: why are you calling `this.handleSubmit(this.props.recipeList);` inside render function?

Comment: You define `this.state = { fetchedJson: [] }` in your constructor. So, on the very first render, when the API has not been called yet, there is no such thing as `this.state.fetchedJson.responseData`. Thus, you're calling `undefined.map()` and as the error tells you, `undefined` doesn't have a `.map` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do side effects inside the `render` function. For this purpose, you have to use [lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class) (or [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) for functional components).

Also `axios.get` is an asynchronous function, so in your code, you make an API call to a server and try to map through `this.state.fetchedJson.responseData` until you receive a response. In this case, `fetchedJson` is an empty object and therefore `fetchedJson.responseData` is `undefined`.

This code should work:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export class ResultTable extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fetchedJson: {},
            isLoaded: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //move side effect (API call) to componentDidMount
        this.handleSubmit(this.props.recipeList);
    };

    handleSubmit(selectedRecipes) {
        if (!this.state.isLoaded) {
            let url =
                "http://localhost:8080/ingredients/?recipes=" +
                selectedRecipes.join(",");
            axios.get(url).then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    fetchedJson: res.data,
                    isLoaded: true
                });
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        //check that you received data before try to render it
        return this.state.isLoaded ? (
            <div>
                <h1 align="center">Ingredients</h1>
                <table border="1" align="center">
                    <tbody>
                    {this.state.fetchedJson.responseData.map(function(ingredient, ingredientIndex) {
                        return (
                            <tr key={ingredientIndex}>
                                <td>{ingredient.name}</td>
                                <td>{ingredient.amount}</td>
                                <td>{ingredient.unit}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        ) : (
            <div>Loading...</div>
        );
    }
}
```